Gitea to Gitea Bulk migration
I already have a Gitea server at one location running version v1.21.3. For some reasons, I also needed to start a separate new Gitea instance, on a different server, I chose v1.22.4 (latest at the moment) for this installation. I know there already exists a migration wizard for individual repositories to migrate one repository at a time from one Gitea instance to another.
I wanted to ask if there already exists a tool to Bulk migrate all the repos, all packages, from one Gitea instance to another.
I also know there is one way to zip all info and copy that over to the new gitea instance, unzip it and all, but that requires the shell access to old gitea instance. Is there any other more efficient way?
